# How do I prevent Windows Error Reporting from deleting my live kernel dump file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-error-reporting, dump, windbg

I have a system (Windows 10, version 20H2, OS Build 19042.1052) that locks up regularly for a few minutes. It doesn't crash/blue screen, but a live kernel dump is logged in the Application event log:

Windows Error Reporting event id 1001:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 1a1
P2: ffffe08a2d98c540
P3: 0
P4: 0
P5: 0
P6: 10_0_19042
P7: 0_0
P8: 256_1
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\WINDOWS\LiveKernelReports\PoW32kWatchdog\PoW32kWatchdog-20210615-0615.dmp
\\?\C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\WER-417554453-0.sysdata.xml
\\?\C:\WINDOWS\LiveKernelReports\PoW32kWatchdog-20210615-0615.dmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER76C9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER76DA.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER76E8.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7709.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Kernel_1a1_b56071bcde394c864256bb672ce88048e33283f_00000000_cab_23199732-b72b-44e5-b26f-f179c6892d31

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 23199732-b72b-44e5-b26f-f179c6892d31
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket: 
Cab Guid: 0
```

I would like to view the PoW32kWatchdog-20210615-0615.dmp file in WinDbg.exe so I can see the stack trace of the faulting thread. However, the .dmp file is nowhere to be found:

C:\WINDOWS\LiveKernelReports\ -> the file is no longer there, presumably because Windows Error Reporting attached it to its report
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Kernel_1a1_b56071bcde394c864256bb672ce88048e33283f_00000000_cab_23199732-b72b-44e5-b26f-f179c6892d31 -> does no longer exist, presumably because the report has been sent to Microsoft before I am able to access it
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Kernel_1a1_b56071bcde394c864256bb672ce88048e33283f_00000000_cab_23199732-b72b-44e5-b26f-f179c6892d31 -> I find a report.wer file here, but it is an name-value-pair file of a few kb, not the .dmp file I'm looking for.

How do I prevent Windows Error Reporting from deleting the .dmp file? Or is there another way to make a copy / backup of the .dmp file before it is deleted by Windows Error Reporting?

Comment: I have investigated this a bit further and found the following article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings 
It seems there is a registry subkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ConfigureArchive of type REG_DWORD that can be set to value 2 to keep an archive of a cab file with all collected files, including the dump file. I have configured this now on my system and will check if it works as expected.